# Merge objects in arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have three objects in two arrays:

```
var tab1 = [{"foo":"bar"}, {"foo2":"bar2"}, {"foo3":"bar3"} ];

var tab2 = [ {"2foo":"2bar"}, {"2foo2":"2bar2"}, {"2foo3":"2bar3"} ];
```

My goal is merge that arrays like this:

```
 var tab3 = [ {"foo":"bar", "2foo":"2bar"},  {"foo2":"bar2",
 "2foo2":"2bar2"},  {"foo3":"bar3", "2foo3":"2bar3"}  ];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This question has good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629817/getting-a-union-of-two-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can use [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

It does exactly what you want.

Example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tab1.length; i++) {
    tab1[i] = $.extend(tab1[i], tab2[i]);
}
```

Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fCx9C/2/

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can see how they implement *jQuery.extend()* [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js).

If you do want to use jQuery, here's the *jQuerified* loop:

```
$.each(tab1, function (i, t) {
    t = $.extend(t, tab2[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/VKpfv/)

```
function merge(obj1, obj2) {
    var tmp = {};
    for (var key in obj1) {
        tmp[key] = obj1[key];
    };
    for (key in obj2) {
        tmp[key] = obj2[key];
    };
    return tmp;
};

function zip(arr1, arr2) {
    var tmp = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = arr1.length; i < len; i++) {
        tmp[i] = merge(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
    };
    return tmp;
};

var tab1 = [{"foo":"bar"}, {"foo2":"bar2"}, {"foo3":"bar3"} ];

var tab2 = [ {"2foo":"2bar"}, {"2foo2":"2bar2"}, {"2foo3":"2bar3"} ];

console.log(zip(tab1, tab2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
var merge = function(t1, t2) { 
    var arr = []; 
    for(i=0; i<t1.length; i++) { 
        for(var prop in t2[i]) { 
            arr.push(t1[i]); 
            arr[i][prop] = t2[i][prop]; 
        } 
    } 
    return arr; 
}

var tab3 = merge(tab1, tab2);
```

Comment: You're right, it does. Though, I wasn't sure how transient the variables would be and if merging was okay. If merging isn't okay - flavs solution is the one to go with.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in vanilla JavaScript quite nicely:

```
var tab1 = [{"foo":"bar"}, {"foo2":"bar2"}, {"foo3":"bar3"} ];
var tab2 = [ {"2foo":"2bar"}, {"2foo2":"2bar2"}, {"2foo3":"2bar3"} ];
var tab3 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(var j in tab2[i]) {
        tab1[i][j] = tab2[i][j];
    }
    tab3.push(tab1[i]);
}
console.log(tab3);
```

However, you don't even have to create a `tab3` array as it puts everything nicely into `tab1` already.