# Get value from Json object with unique key

Tags: javascript, json

How do I check if a JSON object have key are duplicate, just get distint the key and not use foreach function? Such as:

```
var objectData = {[value1: abc], [value1: abc], [value2: bcd]}
```

If a key doesn't exist, and I try to access it, will it return undefined? Or get the error?

Comment: your object is an array and your arrays are objects. => `[{value1: abc}, {value1: abc}, {value2: bcd}]`

Comment: Think how can I check the key in an object if it has duplicate not using "for" or "for each"?

Comment: the key duplicate or the value of a object's key is duplicate?

Comment: Right now, objectData is an object that is full of arrays.  Is that intended?  Or is objectData supposed to be an array of objects?  Or is objectData supposed by an object, with multiple objects as its properties?

Comment: Yes, above just a sample. I just want to check key is duplicate in an object not use "for" function, that it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate objects from an array using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501441/remove-duplicate-objects-from-an-array-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant to be an array of JSON objects:

```
var objectData = [ {"value1": "abc"}, {"value1": "abc"}, {"value2": "bcd"} ];
```

Then your answer lies within the responses to this question: [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) or this one [Remove duplicate objects from an array using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501441/remove-duplicate-objects-from-an-array-using-javascript).

If your notation accurately reflects what is produced by your system (or your own coding), you may want to rework it a bit so it makes sense.

Hope that helps.