# How to remove duplicate objects from an array based on more than one criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

I am trying to find duplicate objects from array by camparing more than 1 field inside object.

I want to compare 2 fields of the object with the other objects of the same array.

I want to campare just name and lname ignoring the 3rd field `link` inside my object

```js
  values = [{
    name: 'newton',
    lname: 'king',
    link: '123'
  }, {
    name: 'tom',
    lname: 'kurtz',
    link: '123'
  }, {
    name: 'newton',
    lname: 'king',
    link: '456'
  }, {
    name: 'jan',
    lname: 'heckal',
    link: '123'
  }]
```

How do I find and remove the duplicate objects with output that would look like this

```js
  values = [{
    name: 'newton',
    lname: 'king',
    link: '123'
  }, {
    name: 'tom',
    lname: 'kurtz',
    link: '123'
  }, {
    name: 'jan',
    lname: 'heckal',
    link: '123'
  }]
```

Comment: This question has been answered many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747798/delete-duplicate-elements-from-an-array

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Show effort and code and try to see if it has been answered before

Comment: [Just _how_ could you miss an answer...](https://www.google.rs/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20remove%20duplicates%20from%20array)

Comment: its really bad guys. i just joined the group and you guys giving me -1.. its hurts lot

Comment: @NicholasRobinson that answer is helpful but you know.. i have to campare more than 1 object with each other

Comment: So show you already know how to remove duplicates and then show and ask us about the code you wrote that fails to compare more than one object. The better the questions the better the answers and some good questions gets voted UP.

Comment: can you please tell me, how to campare more than 1 object

Comment: Show me the objects and the output and the code you tried and I will gladly try to help you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jehyc7vp/  check this out for exact answer

Comment: i didn't find a way to campare muliple objects inside 1 array. can you please help me with this

Comment: check the fiddle first. You can take only one key from the object and push in the array and check the subsequent objects using only one key. The entire array is filtered.

Comment: Thanks @ajaykumar . thats quite useful but i have a question that. can you guide me.  suppose we have 3 fields in one object and we want to campare only 2 fields with other objects.. is that possible?

Comment: @ajaykumar you have to handle "newton first" and "newton second" one of which will disappear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501441/remove-duplicate-objects-from-an-array-using-javascript

Comment: @ManpreetOberoi You need to pust that comment into the question with objects that reflect exactly what you want to do. The question is now different than the title. You possibly need to ask : _How to remove duplicate objects from an array based on more than one criteria_ test data:         `{ name: 'newton', initial: 'a', lname: 'king'},         { name: 'tom', initial: 'b', lname: 'kurtz'},        { name: 'newton', initial: 'b', lname: 'king'},`

Comment: yes.. this is exactly my question man

Comment: can you please help me with this

Comment: I just did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501441/remove-duplicate-objects-from-an-array-using-javascript - just add the fields that you need to compare on

Comment: that is not much helpful.. can you type the answer please...

Comment: That is not what SO is for. If you update your question to show what you mean I may answer it. BUt you COULD take the answer I gave you, plug in your data, see if it worked and come back with the failing code to ask us a real question

Comment: okay i am updating my question

Comment: Great. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask AND http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Then visit the link I gave, here is a version with a LOT of comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37979616/295783

Comment: i also found that...  thanks lot... now you think.. my question was good question.... i hope you will take back your -1. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost a duplicate of [Remove duplicate objects from an array using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501441/remove-duplicate-objects-from-an-array-using-javascript)

```js
 var arrResult=[],
     arr = [{
    name: 'newton',
    lname: 'king',
    link: '123'
  }, {
    name: 'tom',
    lname: 'kurtz',
    link: '123'
  }, {
    name: 'newton',
    lname: 'king',
    link: '456'
  }, {
    name: 'jan',
    lname: 'heckal',
    link: '123'
  }]

for (i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    arrResult[ item.name + " - " + item.lname ] = item; // create associative array
}

var i = 0;
var nonDuplicatedArray = [];    
for(var item in arrResult) {
    nonDuplicatedArray[i++] = arrResult[item]; // copy the objects that are now unique
}
console.log(nonDuplicatedArray)
```