# Create unique array from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following Array

```
var x = [
  '{"id":"item1","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item1","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item2","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item2","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item3","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item2","val":"Items"}'
];
```

I want create unique array by `id` key like following:

```
[
  '{"id":"item1","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item2","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item3","val":"Items"}'
];
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501441/remove-duplicate-objects-from-an-array-using-javascript

Comment: Is x an array of strings or objects ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```js
var x = [
  '{"id":"item1","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item1","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item2","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item2","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item3","val":"Items"}',
  '{"id":"item2","val":"Items"}'
];

var unique = x.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index == self.indexOf(elem);
})

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could use jQuery:

```
var obj = {};
$.each(x,function(index,val){
 var temp = JSON.parse(val);
 obj[temp.id] = val;
})

var tempArray = [];

for(var i in obj){
tempArray.push(obj[i])
}

console.log(tempArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 has been officially published one and half years ago, why not give it a try?

```
var unique = [...new Set(x)]
```

[**`Set`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove the duplicates, [**`...`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to spread members in an iterable.