# how to find totally duplicate object in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

Here is an example js array:

```
var arr = [
  {
    name: 'test1',
    price: 20,
    otherKey: 123,
    yetAnotherKey: 'val'
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    price: 10,
    otherKey: 11,
    yetAnotherKey: 'erewrwert'
  },
  {
    name: 'test1',
    price: 20,
    otherKey: 123,
    yetAnotherKey: 'val'
  }
]
```

Is there a way to find duplicate object (**by all key/value pairs**)?
If so - how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501441/remove-duplicate-objects-from-an-array-using-javascript

Comment: What is expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive approach: Note the inefficiency of using `forEach`. A force iteration over all the item even if a match was found.

```
var arr = [
      {
        name: 'test1',
        price: 20,
        otherKey: 123,
        yetAnotherKey: 'val'
      },
      {
        name: 'test2',
        price: 10,
        otherKey: 11,
        yetAnotherKey: 'erewrwert'
      },
      {
        name: 'test1',
        price: 20,
        otherKey: 123,
        yetAnotherKey: 'val'
      }
    ]

    function findFirstDuplicate(arr) {
      var retval = null
      arr.forEach(function(item) {
        arr.forEach(function(item2) {
            if(JSON.stringify(item) == JSON.stringify(item2)) {
            retval = item;
          }
        });
      });

      return retval;
    }

    console.log(findFirstDuplicate(arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many subjects on the matter, from deep mapping to external libraries (underscore is recommendable), but most often a JSON string is used. Not optimal, but easiest in use. Combined with an ES6 Set, the unique objects can be obtained with:

```
arr = [...new Set(arr.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse);
```

```js
var arr = [
  {
    name: 'test1',
    price: 20,
    otherKey: 123,
    yetAnotherKey: 'val'
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    price: 10,
    otherKey: 11,
    yetAnotherKey: 'erewrwert'
  },
  {
    name: 'test1',
    price: 20,
    otherKey: 123,
    yetAnotherKey: 'val'
  }
];

arr = [...new Set(arr.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Undescore JS](http://underscorejs.org/) library?

> uniq_.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iteratee]) Alias: unique 
>   Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using === to test object equality. In particular only the first occurence of each value is kept. If you know in advance that the array is sorted, passing true for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an iteratee function.
>
> _.uniq([1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3]);
>
> => [1, 2, 4, 3]

Since you want to implement for objects, here are plenty solutions using `_.uniq()` which you might want to have a look at - [Removing duplicate objects with Underscore for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9923890/1182982)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it’s enough to just decide whether an object `o1` is a duplicate of `o2` or not, you can try the following:

```
function isDuplicate(o1, o2) {
  return JSON.stringify(o1) == JSON.stringify(o2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution using a map with the stringified element as the key

```js
var arr = [
      {
        name: 'test1',
        price: 20,
        otherKey: 123,
        yetAnotherKey: 'val'
      },
      {
        name: 'test2',
        price: 10,
        otherKey: 11,
        yetAnotherKey: 'erewrwert'
      },
      {
        name: 'test1',
        price: 20,
        otherKey: 123,
        yetAnotherKey: 'val'
      }
    ]

function solution(arr) {
  let map = new Map();
  let res = [];
  arr.forEach(e => {
    let currKey = JSON.stringify(e);
    // if not seen by the map, put in the the map and push element to result array
    if (!map.get(currKey)) {
      map.set(currKey, true);
      res.push(e);
    } 
  });
  return res;
}

console.log(solution(arr))
```