# How to write a self chain function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Right now, what I want to do is write an `Array.prototype` function `union( array_to_union )`, and I want to call it like this below:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
a.union([2,3,4]).union([1,3,4]) ......
```

and the result will be the union of those array, I wonder how can I do that?

I only know I should use `Array.prototype.union = function( array_to_union){.....}`.

Comment: You would just `return` the array instance in your union function.

Comment: @incutonez Thanks! But I am very new to JS, could you give me some code example?

Comment: "Put code here" questions are too broad for Stack Overflow.  You need to try something first.

Comment: What is the `union` function supposed to do?

Comment: There's already such a function, it's called `concat()`

Comment: Find union set(max set) among those arrays, for example [1,2,3] union [2,3,4] should [1,2,3,4] and then [1,2,3,4] union [1,3,4] is still [1,2,3,4]

Comment: I guess JavaScript currying is a technique that might work here as a pattern to follow

Comment: @TGH Thanks, could you give me some link for that term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
Array.prototype.union = function (second) {
    return second.reduce(function (array, currentValue) {
        if (this.indexOf(currentValue) === -1) array.push(currentValue);

        return array;
    }, this).sort();
};
```

### Test

```
var a = [1,2,3];
a = a.union([2,3,4]).union([1,3,4]);
```

### Result

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It also sorts the array, as your examples showed in the comments.

Comment: @Kuan OK. I've added some code to do an union.

Answer (score -1):

Union function that can be chained together:

```
Array.prototype.union = function(array_to_union) {
    for (i = 0; i < array_to_union.length; i++) {
        this.push(array_to_union[i]);
    }
    return this;
}


var a = [1,2,3];              
a.union([4,5,6]).union([7,8,9]);
```

Note: in this case, the union function just adds 1 array onto the other (does not care about sorting or distinct values).

JS fiddle with more examples: http://jsfiddle.net/enW2Y/1/

Comment: This is exactly what `concat()` does btw ?

Comment: I know. The asker could just want an example of how to use Array.prototype. The question really needs clarification.

Comment: @Lindsay I agree. I've marked the question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3629817/3210837.