# How to get the union of two arrays

Tags: javascript

Say I have two sets (arrays):

```
a = [1,2,3];
b = [2,3,5];
```

and I want 1,2,3,5 out only.

What is the most terse way to do this? Or, failing that, what is a way to do this?

Comment: Probably answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629817/getting-a-union-of-two-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [2,3,5];

//Concat both arrays [1,2,3,2,3,5]
var result = a.concat(b).filter(function(value, index, self) { //array unique
    return self.indexOf(value) === index; 
});
console.log(result); //[1, 2, 3, 5];
```

Comment: `function unique(x) {
  return x.filter(function(elem, index) { return x.indexOf(elem) === index; });
};
function union(x, y) {
  return unique(x.concat(y));
};` because I have to reuse it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following post should help...about half way down is a union with a library reference.

[How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)