# Create unique array from arrays (Multiple)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Am trying the following

```
Input:
myarray1=['Tag A','Tag B','Tag C']
myarray2=['Tag B','Tag C']
myarray3=['Tag A','Tag D']

Output:

outputArray=['Tag A','Tag B','Tag C','Tag D']
```

The output array should conatin the unique values from the input arrays.

Am trying this in typescript but not able to find the unique values from input array.
Any suggestions how to achieve this in optimal way

Comment: Use concat to create one array and then filter

Comment: In that question duplicates were removed from single array, here the question is from multiple arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items) and [Getting a union of two arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629817)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the merged arrays into a Set and spread that set into results array

```js
myarray1=['Tag A','Tag B','Tag C']
myarray2=['Tag B','Tag C']
myarray3=['Tag A','Tag D']

const uniques = [...new Set(myarray1.concat(myarray2,myarray3))]

console.log(uniques)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it with **ES6** [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
myarray1=['Tag A','Tag B','Tag C']
myarray2=['Tag B','Tag C']
myarray3=['Tag A','Tag D']
const uniqueArr = [...new Set([...myarray1,...myarray1,...myarray3])];
console.log(uniqueArr)
```

Comment: where do you use `destructuring` here?

Comment: @quirimmo sorry my bad. Just used wrong wording :(

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, only using array functions, first you conctainate all of the arrays, then you use the fitler function to simply ensure that there's only ever unique values.

```js
const myarray1 = ['Tag A', 'Tag B', 'Tag C'],
  myarray2 = ['Tag B', 'Tag C'],
  myarray3 = ['Tag A', 'Tag D'];

const mergedArray = Array.concat(myarray1, myarray2, myarray3).filter((s, i, array) => array.indexOf(s) === i);
console.log(mergedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it with `reduce` `Set` and `spread` operator.**

```js
let arr1=['Tag A','Tag B','Tag C']
let arr2=['Tag B','Tag C']
let arr3=['Tag A','Tag D']

let arr = [arr1,arr2,arr3]
let op = [...new Set( arr.reduce((o,c)=>o.concat(c),[]))];

console.log(op);
```