# How to remove extra occurrences of a reference array

Tags: javascript

let's assume that we have two arrays like these:

```
let s1 =  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "B"]  // Note: "B" has been occurred 2 times
let s2 =  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "A", "X", "Y"] // // Note: "B" has been occurred 2 times just like s1 but we have another occurrence for "A"
```

I want to create a new array (`let s3`) based on these two arrays with this rule that we'll remove the element(s) with occurrences more than the same element's occurrence in array `s1`

so the `s3 array` would be like this:

```
let s3 =  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "X", "Y"] // we just removed "A" cause it occurred more than "A" occurances in s1
```

Note that we want anything else (`"X", "Y"`). we just want to handle the **extra occurrences**.

so far I can find the index of repeated occurrences like this but I can't find a way to compare each occurrence to see if it is an extra one or not (complicated):

```js
    let s1 =  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "B"]  
    let s2 =  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "A", "X", "Y"]  

    var s3 = [];  
     
    for (let i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < s1.length; j++) {
     if (s2[i] === s1[j]) {
         s3.push(i);
         break;
  }
}        
  }     
    console.log(s3)
```

My English is poor and I don't know if I could explain the issue or not!

Note: I can simply use `s3 = [...new Set(s2)]` to remove repeated elements but I want something else.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Michael but it's different... I can simply use `s2 = [...new Set(s2)]` to remove repeated elements but I want something else...

Comment: Sorry, reread the question. You want the [union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629817/getting-a-union-of-two-arrays-in-javascript) of the arrays.

Comment: Is this the answer you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array

Comment: Thanks ... I'll try those ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to keep everything originally in `s1` but only add items from `s2` if they aren't already in you can initially set `s3` to `s1`. Then loop over `s2` and if `s1` does *not* have the value then push it into `s3`.

```js
const s1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "B"];
const s2 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "A", "X", "Y"];

const s3 = [...s1];

s2.forEach(d => {
  if (!s1.includes(d)) s3.push(d);
});

console.log(s3);
```

Comment: nice short cut, but what if the first one contains elements who are not in the second?

Comment: What a great shortcut!

Comment: @NinaScholz, since OP explicitly stated that they're only looking to add extra occurrences I  made it this way. Otherwise, elements _not_ in the second will not be handled (removed)

Comment: Nice shortcut. Just change s1 destructuring to `const s3 = [...s1.filter(s => s2.includes(s))];`

Answer (score 2):

You could count the values of the first set and return the values for a given count or if not known then all items.

```js
var s1 =  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "B"],
    s2 =  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "A", "X", "Y"],
    count = s1.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map),
    s3 = s2.filter(v => count.get(v) ? count.set(v, count.get(v) - 1) : !count.has(v));

console.log(...s3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map` and `filter`

- First `Map` the array1 to `[key, value]` format
- Iterate over second array, if it's found in `Map` and value is grater than zero return true else return false,
- If it is not found return true

```js
let s1 =  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "B"]  
let s2 =  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "A", "X", "Y"]  

let map = new Map()

s1.forEach(v=>{
  if(map.has(v)){
    map.set(v,map.get(v)+1)
  } else{
    map.set(v,1)
  }
})

let final = s2.filter(val=>{
  if(map.has(val)){
    if(map.get(val)){
      map.set(val, map.get(val)-1)
      return true
    } 
    return false
  }
  return true
})

console.log(final)
```